# Simple call to php script using AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to javascript and AJAX. I have dynamic HTML table to which I add a new column with a textarea. I create a javascript array storing the name of all the textarea which I wish to pass to my php script. 
Here's my javascript function:

```
function checkout()
{
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "loadmsg.php",
            data : {'file_array' : upload},
            success : function(data)
            {
                if(data.status == 'success')
                alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
            else if(data.status == 'error')
                alert("Error on query!");
            }

        });
}
```

Here upload is a global javascript array that I wish to pass to my php script loadmsg.php.
Here's the loadmsg.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_array']))
{
    $file_array = $_POST['file_array'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Success');</script>";
}
?>
```

But when the checkout function is executed there's no alert box. I have checked that the upload array is not empty.
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
After debugging using Firebug I get the following error in console
`ReferenceError:$ not defined` on the `$.ajax` line

Comment: Where are you getting this line from: `data : {'file_array' : upload}`? Where have you defined `upload`?

Comment: Which alert you need to show?

Comment: what is your expected message?

Comment: @V P I added the alert in php script for debugging. I basically wish to load the upload array in php variable $file_array

Comment: @Rasclatt upload is a global javascript array that I defined and initialized in the same file before the checkout function

Comment: @shawshank do you include jquery file in your script? if not than your code will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include in your head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

javascript

don't forget to add `dataType: "json",` to your `ajax`

```
  function checkout()
    {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url  : "loadmsg.php",
                data : {'file_array' : upload},
                success : function(data)
                {
                    if(data.status == 'success')
                    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                else if(data.status == 'error')
                    alert("Error on query!");
                }

            });
    }
```

php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_array']))
{
    $file_array = $_POST['file_array'];
    $arr['status']='success';
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

Try this

Comment: you want to  `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Success');</script>";` in your web?.

Comment: did ur `alert("Thank you for subscribing!");` worked using this code?

Comment: No the `alert("Thank you for subscribing!)` is not working. I wish to pass the upload array in my php variable

Comment: I just checked I'm getting an error `ReferenceError:$ not defined` on the `$.ajax` line

Comment: hav u included `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`  in your HTML <head> tag??

Answer (score 3):

change your php code like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_array']))
{
    $file_array = $_POST['file_array'];
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
}
?>
```

and some change to your js code

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "loadmsg.php",
        data : {'file_array' : 'upload'},
        success : function(data)
        {
            var response = $.parseJson(data);
            if(response.status == 'success')
            alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
        else if(response.status == 'error')
            alert("Error on query!");
        }

    });
```

Hope it will works

Comment: I still don't get any message

Comment: @Hossain still no alert

Comment: Try `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));` not `return`

Comment: @hossain sorry for typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's working for me:

your script

```
 function checkout()
        {
       $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "form1.php",
                data : {'file_array' : upload},
                success : function(data)
                {
                  var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(data.status == 'success')
                    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                else if(data.status == 'error')
                    alert("Error on query!");
                }

            });
      }
```

your PHP should be.,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_array']))
{
    $file_array = $_POST['file_array'];
    $data['status'] = 'success';

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo variable from backend of AJAX (PHP) file.

Alert is already there in Javscript file.

So, the corrected PHP file is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_array']))
{
    $file_array = $_POST['file_array'];
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```

AND js,

```
success : function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'success')
                alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
            else if(data == 'error')
                alert("Error on query!");
            }
```

You can use Firefox's Firebug to debug this.

Go to `Firebug's` `Console` tab and see which requests are going.

It will show:

- Parameter being posted
- Output from backend file.

From here, you will get exact idea of data flow.

Comment: I did that but I still don't get any message

Comment: I just checked I'm getting an error `ReferenceError:$ not defined` on the `$.ajax` line